# Is it possible to perform skip N rows and fetch M rows without full scan

Tags: oracle, optimization, oracle-11g, row

Let's say I've got this query:

```
SELECT EMP_ID,LAST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES
   WHERE POSITIONID IN (1,3) ORDER BY POSITIONID,LAST_NAME;
```

Now if I want to show only the first ten rows between 50 and 60, the only way I can think of is to first run the above query with ROWNUM pseudocolumn and then select from the result of this query. Something like this:

```
SELECT EMP_ID,LAST_NAME FROM 
 (SELECT  ROWNUM RNUM,EMP_ID,LAST_NAME FROM
  (SELECT EMP_ID,LAST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES
     WHERE POSITIONID IN (1,3) ORDER BY POSITIONID,LAST_NAME))
  WHERE RNUM BETWEEN 50 AND 60;
```

But this way, I'll end up first fetching all the employees whose positions are 1 or 3 and then extract the 10 rows among them. I find this a bit inefficient. Is there any way to achieve this without making full scan first?

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Without an `order by`, the query you posted doesn't do what you appear to want.

Comment: Oracle 11G. Yes you are right. But I wanted to focus on the full scan only so, I omitted that part. Anyway, I'll edit the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard approach to get [rows N through M](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:127412348064) is to do something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*, rownum rnum
          FROM (SELECT emp_id, last_name
                  FROM employees
                 WHERE positionID in (1,3)
                 ORDER BY <<something>>) a
         WHERE rownum <= 60) b
 WHERE rnum > 50
```

Note that you need to include the `order by` in the query in order for it to make sense.  Oracle may use a table scan (depending on whether or not `positionID` and/or the column(s) in the `order by` are indexed) but there will be a stopkey limiter so Oracle knows it can stop scanning the table (or the index) once 60 rows have been read.

In 12.1 and later, you can simplify this a bit

```
SELECT emp_id, last_nae
  FROM employees
 WHERE positionID in (1,3)
 ORDER BY val
OFFSET 50 ROWS
 FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

More examples of using the new [row limit clauses in 12.1](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1)

Comment: So what I understand is, if I need rows between 10k and 15k, then Oracle will at least scan until 15k. Is that correct?

Comment: BTW, the feature added to 12C is like exactly the same with what Microsoft added to SQL Server 2012 :)

Comment: @MikayilAbdullayev - Yes.  Though I would question why you would do such a thing.  You use paging queries when you have humans that want to look through the first few rows of data.  Humans aren't going to read row 10,000.  A computer system that wants to read all the data eventually would not use this sort of query